# Getting Sass::SyntaxError in Home#index error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-4, rubygems

I am learning to import Bootstrap in rails . When I try to run server this message appears:

```
Sass::SyntaxError in Home#index
Showing C:/Users/Admin/.ssh/gazalpro/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #7 raised:

File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.
Load paths:
  C:/Users/Admin/.ssh/gazalpro/app/assets/config
  C:/Users/Admin/.ssh/gazalpro/app/assets/images
  C:/Users/Admin/.ssh/gazalpro/app/assets/javascripts
  C:/Users/Admin/.ssh/gazalpro/app/assets/stylesheets
  C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts
  C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.4.2/lib/assets/compiled
  C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.4.2/app/assets/javascripts
  C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionview-5.2.4.2/lib/assets/compiled
  C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/turbolinks-source-5.2.0/lib/assets/javascripts
  C:/Users/Admin/.ssh/gazalpro/node_modules
```

**Here is application.html.erb :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Gazalpro</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Here is Gemfile :**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.4', '>= 5.2.4.2'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'duktape'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.4', '>= 4.4.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'


# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**Here is Application.js file :**

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

**Here is application.css.scss file:**

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

I have already run the command 'Bundle install' and restarted the server. But I am still getting this error.

Comment: Did you run `bundle install`?

Comment: Did you remove the lines with `*=require` from the `application.scss` file? If you did it already, I would try to run `spring stop` as well and restart the server again...

Comment: Could you upload your code to Github and share the link? So I can actually look at the code.